# Combine List of Objects based on parameters

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have a List(Of Objects). These objects have the properties of carID: int, carColor: string, dateFiled: date, carStyleID: int, carTopSpeed: int, carSafetyRating: int. The last two are tied with the styleID...

There are instances of a carID having multiple carStyleID's.

If I wanted to take this list and convert it into a new list that breaks down based on date occurred and carID, how would I achieve that? For instance:

`carID: 1, carColor: red, dateFiled: 3/1/20, carStyleID: 25, carTopSpeed: 100, carSafetyRating: 7`

`carID: 1, carColor: red, dateFiled: 3/1/20, carStyleID: 29, carTopSpeed: 100, carSafetyRating: 5`

`carID: 2, carColor: blue, dateFiled: 3/1/20, carStyleID: 50, carTopSpeed: 150, carSafetyRating: 8`

`carID: 3, carColor: blue, dateFiled: 3/2/20, carStyleID: 68, carTopSpeed: 200, carSafetyRating: 5`

So, the new list should leave the last two alone, and combine the first two into:

`carID: 1, carColor: red, dateFiled: 3/1/20, OBJECT: where there are two objects now with the remaining data.`

Is there anyway to achieve this in vb.net?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're after?  Is it a List(Of List(Of Object)?

Comment: What type are the original objects? Are they your own class/structure or an anonymous type?

Comment: Are you saying that "carStyleID: 25" *always* has "carTopSpeed: 100, carSafetyRating: 7"?

Comment: You can certainly achieve it using a loop through the list assuming you can sort it by ID first.  It might even be possible to condense it into a statement or a smaller loop using Linq, but I'm not sure about the part where you combine two objects into one.